# Why can't ajax request be executed？

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function search(keywords) {
    $.get(`http://localhost:3000/search?keywords=${keywords}`, function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.searchlist').append(
            `
            <div class="songitem" data-songid="${data.result.songs[0].id}" data-albumimg="${data.result.songs[0].album.picId}">
                <div class="songname">${data.result.songs[0].name}</div>
                <div class="singername">${data.result.songs[0].artists[0].name}</div>
                <div class="album">${data.result.songs[0].album.name}</div>            
            </div>
            `
        )
        
        $('.songitem').on('click', function(){
            console.log('!!')
            let songId = $(this).attr('data-songid');
            console.log(songId)
            $.get(`http://localhost:3000/song/url/v1?id=${songId} & level=exhigh`,function(data,status){
                console.log(data)
                audio.src=data.url;
                audio.play();
                console.log('!')
            })
        });
    })
}

$('.search').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        search($('.search').val());
    }
});
```

I have a search box on my page to search for music. When I enter a keyword, my local server will return the song related to that keyword, then it will be placed on the page, I bind a click event for it, when I click on it it will send an ajax request with the obtained song id as a parameter, but this request does not seem to be sent because '!' is not output to the console. I would like to know what caused this result, thank you all.

Comment: What do you see in the devtools Network panel?

Comment: Most likely you're calling this from a page that wasn't loaded from `http://localhost:3000`, so it's a cross-origin call which is [disallowed by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and you don't have the server set up to serve [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers (and handle an OPTIONS request). (Note that even with CORS, if you've loaded the page from the file system instead of from HTTP/HTTPS, in some browsers you can't do a cross-origin call at all.)